# ASP.NET unable to search without using invisible button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make my first ASP.NET web site and am unable to get searching and paging to work in ASP.NET Web Forms without using an invisible button.  I can't use my search button's click event because it needs to reset my page to 0 when clicked, so it only has a client-click event.  I have to make it call a JavaScript function, which calls the invisible button's click event handler after doing so.  The only way I can figure out around it is to make the page post back to itself and pass the index in from the bottom paging table.  Hopefully, someone here might have some suggestions for an easier way to do it.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.  If it wasn't for paging, it would be one line of code inside my button click event handler.

Here is the relevant markup for my page.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function page(index) 
    {
        document.getElementById('PageIndex').value = index;
        document.getElementById('btnInvisible').click();
    }
</script>
<uc1:ucWidgetSearch runat="server" id="ctl" />
<p id="pHTML" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnInvisible" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" OnClick="btnInvisible_Click" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="PageIndex" runat="server" /
```

Here is the markup for the UserControl on the page.

```
<label>Last Name:</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClientClick="page('0')" />
```

Here is the C# code behind for the .aspx page.  The .aspx page uses no using statements.

```
namespace Widgets.WebUI
{ public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        { ScreenHelper.LoadScreen(ctl.Search(), pHTML, PageIndex);}
        protected void btnInvisible_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        { }
    }
}
```

Here is the code behind for the UserControl.  It also uses no using statements.

```
public partial class ucWidgetSearch : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    internal Widgets.BLL.WidgetSearch Search()
    {
        if (!txtLastName.Enabled)
        {
            txtLastName.Enabled = true;
            txtLastName.Focus();
            return null;
        }
        return new Widgets.BLL.WidgetSearch(txtLastName.Text);
    }
}
```

Finally, there is a ScreenHelper class that calls into the BLL layer, which calls into the DAL layer and constructs an HTML document and passes it into the p element on the main page.

```
internal class ScreenHelper
{
    internal static void LoadScreen(WidgetSearch search, 
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl p, HiddenField page)
    {
        if (search != null)
        {
            try
            {
                p.InnerHtml = WidgetsLogic.GetHTMLTable(search.LastName, int.Parse(page.Value), 20);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                p.InnerHtml = "<label style=\"color: #FF0000\">Error loading screen: " + ex.Message + "</label>";
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace Widgets.BLL
{
    public class WidgetsLogic
    {
        public static string GetHTMLTable(string name, int pageIndex, int? pageSize)
        {
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("<table border=\"1\">");
            List<Widget> list = WidgetsDataAccess.GetByName(name);
            int minDex = 0, maxDex = list.Count;

            if (pageSize == null)
            {
                pageIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pageIndex = HTMLHelper.GetPageIndex(pageIndex, pageSize.Value, list.Count);
                minDex = pageIndex * pageSize.Value;
                maxDex = minDex + pageSize.Value;
                if (maxDex > list.Count)
                    maxDex = list.Count;
            }

            for (int i = minDex; i < maxDex; i++)
            {
                strBuilder.Append("<tr");

                // Set Light Gray Color for alterating rows in table
                if (i%2 != 0) 
                    strBuilder.Append(" style=\"background-color: #EBEBEB\"");

                strBuilder.Append("><td>" + list[i].ID.ToString() + "</td>");
                strBuilder.Append("<td>" + list[i].Name + "</td></tr>");
            }

            strBuilder.Append("</table>");

            // Add Paging if appropriate
            if (pageSize != null && pageSize.Value < list.Count)
            {
                strBuilder.Append(HTMLHelper.GetPagingFooter(pageIndex, pageSize.Value, 
                    list.Count, "javascript:page('@pageIndex')"));
            }

            string str = strBuilder.ToString();

            return str;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this 'reset my page to 0' client side ? Why not just have the search button posting to the server and set the page to be zero when you return the search results?

Comment: The way I'm handling paging is my BLL layer is throwing a table at the bottom of the p element and there are hyperlinks in there that call the javascript function when clicked and pass the page as a parameter and then it calls the invisible button's click.  If it called the actual Search button's click it would get reset to 0, since my search button always resets paging to 0.

Answer (score 0):

you should never try to do paging manually. Rather use `GridView` and an `ObjectDataSource`
to bind data to your page. This way ASP.NET handles the pageIndex exc via viewstate and the `ObjectDatasource` handles paging for you.Check [this link](http://developer.webnodes.com/paging-in-a-gridview-using-an-objectdatasource) for a good example of how to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to refer to the actual ID of an HTML control

```
document.getElementById('<%= PageIndex.ClientID %>').value = index;
```